# Convert 1.5 template to 3.x

Tags: templates

I'm trying to convert a relatively simple 1.5 Joomla template to work in a 3.x install. I followed the directions here: https://docs.joomla.org/Migrating_a_Template_from_Joomla_1.5_to_3.x but it's still not working. I converted these params in "params.ini" to the following in the "templateDetails.xml":

widthStyle=fluid
templateColor=grey
showComponent=1

to

```
<config>
    <fields name="params">
         <fieldset name="advanced">
            <field name="widthStyle" class="" type="text" default="fluid" label="TPL widthStyle" description="widthStyle" />
            <field name="templateColor" class="" type="color" default="#808080" label="TPL templateColor" description="templateColor" />
            <field name="showComponent" class="" type="checkbox" default="1" label="TPL showComponent" description="showComponent" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
 </config>
```

then it appeared to install fine, but the template isn't loading with this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in
>   /home/x/public_html/J3/templates/siteground-j15-30/index.php on line
>   60

which seems to happen around these lines

```
<?php  if($this->countModules('right') and error->getCode();quest::getCmd('layout') != 'form') : ?>
<div id="maincolumn">
<?php else: ?>
<div id="maincolumn_full">
<?php endif; ?>
```

if I remove this part, I still get another error:

> Deprecated: Non-static method JPlugin::loadLanguage() should not be
>   called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in
>   /home/x/public_html/J3/templates/siteground-j15-30/index.php on line 3

This is what I've got currently after a few modifications:

index.hp

```
<?php 
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
JPlugin::loadLanguage( 'tpl_SG1' );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >
<?php $app = Jfactory::getApplication();?>
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body id="page_bg">
    <div id="all">
        <div id="top">  
            <div class="pill_m">
                <div id="pillmenu">
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user3"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="search">
                <?php if($this->countModules('user4')) :?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user4" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="middle"></div>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.php"><?php echo $app->getCfg('sitename');?></a>
            </div>  
                    <div id="top-banner">
                    <div id="top-spacer">
                <?php if($this->countModules('user1')) :?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="xhtml"/>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <?php if($this->countModules('user2')) :?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2" style="xhtml"/>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="center">        
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="area"> 

                    <div id="content">  
                        <div id="leftcolumn">   
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="rounded" />
                            <?php $sg = 'banner'; include "templates.php"; ?>
                        </div>


                        <?php  if($this->countModules('right') and $this->error->getCode();quest::getCmd('layout') != 'form') : ?>
                        <div id="maincolumn">
                        <?php else: ?>
                        <div id="maincolumn_full">
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="nopad">
                        <?php if($this->countModules('user5')) :?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user5" style="rounded"/>
                <?php endif; ?>


                                <jdoc:include type="message" />
                                <?php $params = $app->getParams(); if($params->get('showComponent')) : ?>
                                    <jdoc:include type="component" />
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <div id="container">
                                <div id="user6">
                                <?php if($this->countModules('user6')) :?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user6" style="rounded"/>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div id="user7">
                <?php if($this->countModules('user7')) :?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user7" style="rounded"/>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div id="user8">
                <?php if($this->countModules('user8')) :?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user8" style="rounded"/>
                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div></div></div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="rightcolumn" style="float: right;">
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="rounded" />                                
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>              
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />    
    <div id="content_bottom"></div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>
                Valid <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer">XHTML</a> and <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">CSS</a>.
            </p>
            <div id="sgf">
                <?php $sg = ''; include "templates.php"; ?>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

templates.php

```
<?if( $sg == 'banner' ):?>
<div style="width:137px;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;">
<br />
<table style="width:137px;text-align:center;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td><font class="sgf1">Menorca Net</font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="width:137px;height:16px;text-align:center;border:none;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td width="2" height="16"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
</div>  
<?else:?>
    <?php echo $app->getCfg('sitename') ;?> 1995-2017<?endif;?>
```

css file

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

form {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img,table {
    border: none;
}

body {
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666;
    background: url(../images/bg.jpg) top left;
}

body.contentpane {
    background: url(../images/bg.jpg) bottom left repeat-x;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #555;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #333;
}

input.button, .validate  {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 10px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

input.button:hover, .validate:hover  {

}

p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.inputbox {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #666;
    padding: 2px;
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
.inputbox:hover {

}

#search .search .inputbox {
    width: 130px;
    height: 14px;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 6px 0 0 18px;
    background: none;
}

/*****************************************/
/*** Template specific layout elements ***/
/*****************************************/
#all {
    background: url(../images/gradient.jpg) top left repeat-x;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}

#top {
    width: 995px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#page_bg {
    padding: 0;
}

div.center {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 993px;
    border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    border-left: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}

div#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 993px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #f9f9f9 url(../images/content.jpg) top left repeat-x;
}

#middle {
    background: url(../images/middle.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    width: 995px;
    height: 7px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0;
}

#header {
    background: url(../images/header.jpg) top left repeat-x;
    width: 995px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 206px;
}

#top-banner {
float: right;
width: 728px;
margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
#top-spacer {
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#content {
    width: 995px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo {
float: left;
    padding: 40px 0 0 40px;
    text-align: left;
    /*margin: 0 auto;*/
/*  width: 345px; */
    width: 200px;
}

#logo a, #logo a:link, #logo a:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #5a8c94;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    line-height: 36px;
}

.pill_m {
    width: 795px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}

#pillmenu {
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
}

#pillmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#pillmenu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(../images/menu_li.jpg) top right no-repeat;
}

#pillmenu li:hover {

}

#pillmenu li a#active_menu-nav {
    color: #5f5f5f;
}

#pillmenu li a {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    color: #8f8f8f;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(../images/menu_li_a.jpg) top left no-repeat;
}

#pillmenu li a:hover {
    color: #5f5f5f;
}

#search {   
    width: 190px;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: left;
    background: url(../images/search.jpg) top right no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: right;
}

#area {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#leftcolumn {
    margin: 8px;
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

#rightcolumn {
    margin: 8px ;
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

div#maincolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 603px !important;
    width: 595px;
    margin: 8px 0;
}

div#maincolumn_full {
    float: left;
    width: 759px;
    margin: 8px 0;
}
#user6 {
width: 49%;
float: left;
}
#user7 {
width: 49%;
float: right;
}
#user8 {
width: 100%;
float: left;
}
div.nopad {
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.nopad ul {
    clear: both;
}

td.middle_pad {
    width: 20px;
}

#banner_l {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 24px;
}

#content_bottom {
    background: url(../images/content_bottom.jpg) bottom center no-repeat;
    height: 2px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0;
}

#footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#footer p {
    height: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px 30px 0 0;
    color: #666;
}

/*****************************************/
/*** Joomla! specific content elements ***/
/*****************************************/

div.offline {
    background: #fffebb;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 5px;
}

/* headers */
div.componentheading {
    height: 22px;
    padding: 0 0 0 4px;
}
table.blog {

}
h1 {
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: #333;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

h2, .contentheading {
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #0099cc;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}

table.contentpaneopen h3 {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

h4 {
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}

h3, .componentheading, table.moduletable th, legend {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #555;
    padding: 0;
}
/* small text */
.small {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
}

.modifydate {
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: right;
}

.createdate {
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

a.readon {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    padding: 1px 2px 1px 2px;
    color: #666;
}
a.readon:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* form validation */
.invalid { border-color: #ff0000; }
label.invalid { color: #ff0000; }


/** overlib **/

.ol-foreground {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #333;
}

.ol-background {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #333;
}

.ol-textfont {
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.ol-captionfont {
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #f6f6f6;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #f6f6f7;
}
.ol-captionfont a {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.ol-closefont {}

/* menu links */
a.mainlevel:link, a.mainlevel:visited {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

a.mainlevel:hover {

}

/* spacers */
span.article_separator {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
}

.article_column {

}

.column_separator {

}

td.buttonheading {
    text-align: right;
    width: 0;
}

.clr {
    clear: both;
}

table.blog span.article_separator {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
}



/* table of contents */
table.contenttoc {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

table.contenttoc td {
  padding: 0 5px;
}


/* content tables */
td.sectiontableheader {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: #e7e7e7;
}

tr.sectiontableentry0 td,
tr.sectiontableentry1 td,
tr.sectiontableentry2 td {
  padding: 4px;
}

td.sectiontableentry0,
td.sectiontableentry1,
td.sectiontableentry2 {
  padding: 3px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 11px;
}


/* content styles */
.contentpaneopen, table.contentpane {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table.contentpane td{
    text-align: left;
}

table.contentpane td.contentdescription {
    width: 100%;
}

table.contentpane  {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8px;
}

table.contentpane ul li a .category {
    color: #FF8800;
}

table.contentpane ul li {
    color: #333;
}

table.contentpaneopen {
    margin: 2px 4px;
}

table.contentpaneopen li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

table.contentpaneopen fieldset {
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #669933;
}

table.contentpaneopen h3 {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

table.contentpaneopen h4 {
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #669933;
}

.highlight {
    background-color: #fffebb;
}

/* module control elements */
table.user1user2 div.moduletable {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

div.module_menu, div.module, div.module_text {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 14px 0;
}

div.module_menu div, div.module div, div.module_text div {
    padding: 0;
    background: #e2e2e2;
}

div.module_menu div div, div.module div div, div.module_text div div {
    padding: 1px;
}

div.module_menu div div div, div.module div div div, div.module_text div div div{
    padding: 0 0 1px 0;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}

div.module_menu div div div div, div.module div div div div {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

div.module_menu div div div form, div.module div div div form{
    padding: 6px 0 6px 0;
}




div.module_menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}

div.module_menu ul li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.module_menu ul li a:link, div.module_menu ul li a:visited {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: transparent url(../images/blue/bullet2.jpg) top left no-repeat;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 25px;
    line-height: 24px;
}


#leftcolumn div.module table ,#rightcolumn div.module table {

}

#leftcolumn div.module table.poll {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* LEFT COL H3 */
#leftcolumn h3, #rightcolumn h3, #maincolumn h3, #maincolumn_full h3 {  
    color: #666;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 26px;
    /*width: 170px;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    background: url(../images/h3.jpg) top left repeat-x;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 26px;
}
#leftcolumn h3, #rightcolumn h3 {
width: 168px;
}
#maincolumn .moduletble h3 {
width: 564px;
}
#maincolumn_full .moduletable h3 {
width: 752px;
}
#leftcolumn .moduletable_menu, #leftcolumn .moduletable, #leftcolumn .moduletable_text, #leftcolumn .c, 
#rightcolumn .moduletable_menu, #rightcolumn .moduletable, #rightcolumn .moduletable_text, #rightcolumn .c {
    margin: 0 0 16px 0;
    padding: 6px 10px;
}

#leftcolumn .moduletable form, #leftcolumn .module_text .bannergroup_text,
#rightcolumn .moduletable form, #rightcolumn .module_text .bannergroup_text {
    padding: 6px 10px;
}

#leftcolumn ul.menu, #rightcolumn ul.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    list-style: none;
}

#leftcolumn ul.menu li, #rightcolumn ul.menu li {
    margin: 0 4px 0 4px;
    padding: 0;
}

#leftcolumn ul.menu li:hover, #rightcolumn ul.menu li:hover {

}

/*LEFT COL LINK*/
#leftcolumn ul.menu li a, #leftcolumn ul.menu li a:link,
#rightcolumn ul.menu li a, #rightcolumn ul.menu li a:link {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: url(../images/menu_row.jpg) center left no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
}

#leftcolumn ul.menu li a:hover, #rightcolumn ul.menu li a:hover {
    color: #333;
}

/*LEFT COL CURRENT LINK*/
#leftcolumn ul.menu li#current a, #leftcolumn ul.menu li#current a:link, 
#rightcolumn ul.menu li#current a, #rightcolumn ul.menu li#current a:link {
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0;
}

#leftcolumn ul.menu li#current a:hover, #rightcolumn ul.menu li#current a:hover {

}

/*LEFT COL SUB LINK*/
#leftcolumn ul.menu li#current ul li a, #leftcolumn ul.menu li#current ul li a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: url(../images/sub_menu_row.jpg) center left no-repeat;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 18px;
    border: none;
}

#leftcolumn ul.menu li ul li#current a, #leftcolumn ul.menu li ul li#current a:link, #leftcolumn ul.menu li ul li#current a:visited, #leftcolumn ul.menu li ul li#current a:hover {
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    color: #333;
}
/*SUBMENU POSITION*/
#leftcolumn ul.menu li#current ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#leftcolumn ul.menu li#current ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*CURRENT SUBMENU POSITION*/
#leftcolumn ul.menu li ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 6px;
}

#leftcolumn ul.menu li#current ul li a:hover {
    color: #333;
}

#leftcolumn ul.menu li ul, #rightcolumn ul.menu li ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/* forms */
#leftcolumn .moduletable ul, #rightcolumn .moduletable ul {
    margin:6px 0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

#leftcolumn .moduletable ul li, #rightcolumn .moduletable ul li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 2px;
}

table.adminform textarea {
  width: 540px;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000099;
}

div.search input {
    width: 90px;
    border: 0;
    height: 15px;
}

form#form-login fieldset { 
    border: 0 none; 
    margin: 0; 
}
form#form-login ul li{ 
    padding: 0; 
}

form#form-login ul li a {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #555;
}

/* thumbnails */
div.mosimage         {  margin: 5px; }
div.mosimage_caption {  font-size: .90em; color: #333; }

div.caption       { padding: 0 10px 0 10px; }
div.caption img   { border: 1px solid #CCC; }
div.caption p     { font-size: .90em; color: #333; text-align: center; }

/* Parameter Table */
table.paramlist {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

table.paramlist td.paramlist_key {
    width: 128px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 30px;
}

table.paramlist td.paramlist_value {
}

div.message {
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size : 14px;
    color : #c30;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: solid 1px #d5d5d5;
    margin: 3px 0px 10px;
    padding: 3px 20px;
}

/* Banners module */

/* Default skyscraper style */
.bannergroup {
}

.banneritem {
}

/* Text advert style */

.banneritem_text {
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.bannerfooter_text {
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: right;
}

/* System Messages */
/* see system general.css */

.pagination span { padding: 2px; }
.pagination a    { padding: 2px; }

/* Polls */
.pollstableborder td {
    text-align: left;
}

/* Frontend Editing*/
fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
}

legend {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

td.key {
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    color: #333;
}

/* Tooltips */
.tool-tip {
    float: left;
    background: #ffc;
    border: 1px solid #D4D5AA;
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 200px;
}

.tool-title {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: -15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: url(../../system/images/selector-arrow.png) no-repeat;
}

.tool-text {
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

/* System Standard Messages */
#system-message dd.message ul { 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: none;
    border: none;
}

/* System Error Messages */
#system-message dd.error ul { 
    color: #c00; 
    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* System Notice Messages */
#system-message dd.notice ul { 
    color: #c00; 
    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#system-message dd {
    text-indent: 0;
}

#system-message dd ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #c00; 
    background: none;
    border: none;
}

#system-message {
    margin-top: 5px;
}



/* ****************************************************************************** */
/* blue */
input, button {

}
/* blue */
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]{
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
}

/* -------------------------- */
a.sgfooter:link, a.sgfooter:visited {
    color: #555;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.sgfooter:hover {
    color: #555;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#sgf {
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #555;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.sgf {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sgf1 {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #555;
    text-align: left;
}

a.sglink:link, a.sglink:visited {
    color: #555;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.sglink:hover {
    color: #555;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few errors within your template. Try the following which fixes them, uses HTML5 doctype and some other coding standard improvements:

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('tpl_SG1', JPATH_SITE, 'en-GB', true);

$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$app    = JFactory::getApplication();
$params = $app->getParams();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>">
<head>
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/system/css/system.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template.css">
</head>
<body id="page_bg">
    <div id="all">
        <div id="top">  
            <div class="pill_m">
                <div id="pillmenu">
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user3" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="search">
                <?php if ($this->countModules('user4')) : ?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user4" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="middle"></div>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <a href="index.php"><?php echo $config->get('sitename');?></a>
            </div>  
            <div id="top-banner">
                <div id="top-spacer">
                    <?php if ($this->countModules('user1')) : ?>
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user1" style="xhtml" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <?php if ($this->countModules('user2')) : ?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user2" style="xhtml" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="center">        
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="area"> 
                    <div id="content">  
                        <div id="leftcolumn">   
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="rounded" />
                            <?php $sg = 'banner'; include_once 'templates.php'; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php if ($this->countModules('right') && $config->get('layout') !== 'form') : ?>
                            <div id="maincolumn">
                        <?php else: ?>
                        <div id="maincolumn_full">
                        <?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="nopad">
                                <?php if ($this->countModules('user5')) : ?>
                                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user5" style="rounded" />
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <jdoc:include type="message" />

                                <?php if ($params->get('showComponent')) : ?>
                                    <jdoc:include type="component" />
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <div id="container">
                                    <div id="user6">
                                        <?php if ($this->countModules('user6')) : ?>
                                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user6" style="rounded" />
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="user7">
                                        <?php if ($this->countModules('user7')) : ?>
                                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user7" style="rounded" />
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="user8">
                                        <?php if ($this->countModules('user8')) : ?>
                                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user8" style="rounded" />
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="rightcolumn" style="float: right;">
                            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="rounded" />                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>              
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />    
        <div id="content_bottom"></div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Valid <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer">XHTML</a> and <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">CSS</a>.</p>
            <div id="sgf">
                <?php $sg = ''; include_once 'templates.php'; ?>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I haven't tested this so it may need tweaking.

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the errors and the template now renders, although it's not functional, i.e can't enter any text in the search box, and clicking on any menu item to load an article results in a blank page (just the basic template with the menus)

Comment: Modules seem to display correctly as most of the features (search box is kinda missplaced and the font on an old menus component isn't working properly), but it's not showing any articles at all. I tried with a single article on the home page, or a module with the latest articles: empty (the module title shows up)

Comment: With the article not showing, perhaps you have the `showComponent` parameter for your template set to "**No**". If modules are misplaced then you need to fix your styling. Out of all honestly, I wouldn't port this over to Joomla 3.x.....I'd simply get a new template, or base a new template off the default Protostar one